# Using Apache Jena - including TDB dataset in Fuseki

Tags: java, rdf, jena, fuseki, tdb

i'm pretty new to Apache Jena and i've got some problems. I initialized a TDB dataset with

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(my/desired/directory);
```

I will fill this dataset with a model by adding `Statements` to a `Model` with the following code:

```
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    try{
        model = dataset.getNamedModel(modelName);

        Statement stmt = model.createStatement
                (
                    model.createResource(subject),
                    model.createProperty(property),
                    model.createResource(object)
                );

        model.add(stmt);
        dataset.commit();
    } finally {
        if (model != null) model.close();
        dataset.end();
}
```

That's it. After looking to `my/desired/path` i find a directory (size = 192MB).

Why is this dataset so big?!

But my initial question is: How can i integrate this dataset via Java API to my running Fuseki-Server? I'm able to integrate a model with the `DataAccessorFactory` and the `createHTTP`-method.

Can you help me? Any answer is appreciated, because i've got a big lack of understanding the syntax here.

Thanks, FFoDWindow.

Comment: The files used in an empty database are sparse files - requested that size from the OS but not touched. On Linux, the size of an empty database under 160K of allocated space (try "du -sh"), yet several file sizes are 8M (try "ls -l"). Different operating systems report the space by different metrics. Whatever the OS, as data is added the first that happens is that it uses up the space reported in that 192M before anything else.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying achieve. (1) Add and manipulate data in a remote server (2) Do you want to publish your dataset to a remote server (3) Run a server in your application that shares the dataset (and so you can continue to modify it).  All are possible; they are different though.

Comment: @AndyS Hey, thanks for your answer! I guess, i want to run server in my application that shares the data. Maybe it's better if i try to explain it more detailed: (1) I want to create a Model with data from XML. (2) Store the Model in a triplestore. (3) Make the data accessible in Fuseki. That are the first things i want to do - later i'll try to visualize it with graphs.

Comment: Do to want to modify the data from the app after launching Fuseki?